# Netplan - configuring 2 vlan on same bonding

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, netplan, network-bonding

On my Ubuntu servers (16.04) I used to create a bonding between 2 interfaces and set 2 adresses on it from 2 different vlan.

I can't manage to create the same configuration with Netplan for my new servers, I only see examples with 1 bonding and 1 address, or 2 vlan but no bonding...

Here is the interface file file I would like to reproduce :

```
auto enp61s0f0
    iface enp61s0f0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    mtu 9000
auto enp61s0f1
    iface enp61s0f1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    mtu 9000
auto bond0
    iface bond0 inet manual
    bond-mode balance-xor
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-slaves none
    mtu 9000
auto bond0.170
    iface bond0.170 inet static
    vlan-raw-device bond0
    address 192.168.170.190
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.170.0
    broadcast 192.168.170.255
    gateway 192.168.170.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.170.100 192.168.170.101
    dns-search network.lan
    mtu 9000
auto bond0.186
    iface bond0.186 inet static
    vlan-raw-device bond0
    address 192.168.186.225
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.186.0
    broadcast 192.168.186.255
    mtu 9000
```

Do you have any idea how I could do it ?

Thank you !

Ludwig

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution :

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp61s0f0:
          match:
            macaddress: a0:42:3f:3a:f7:76
          set-name: enp61s0f0
          mtu: 9000
        enp61s0f1:
          match:
            macaddress: a0:42:3f:3a:f7:77
          set-name: enp61s0f1
          mtu: 9000
    bonds:
        bond0:
          mtu: 9000
          dhcp4: false
          dhcp6: false
          interfaces: [ enp61s0f0, enp61s0f1 ]
          parameters:
            mode: balance-xor
            mii-monitor-interval: 100
    vlans:
        bond0.170:
          id: 170
          link: bond0
          addresses : [192.168.170.190/24]
          gateway4: 192.168.170.1
          nameservers:
            search: [network.lan]
            addresses: [192.168.170.100, 192.168.170.101]
          mtu: 9000
        bond0.186:
          id: 186
          link: bond0
          addresses: [192.168.186.225/24]
          mtu: 9000
```

The MTU settings on every interfaces and vlans seems to be important, moreover it requires to specify mac address for the interfaces.

If you need to set a different MTU on your vlans, you must set the higher under "bond0" like it is above and then change the one you want under vlan section to 1500 for example.

Ludwig